# Why does Ubuntu 16.04 fail to wake up from hibernation after changing swap partition?

Tags: partitioning, 16.04, swap, hibernate, plymouth

I want to understand this.

After:

- changing swap partition,
- setting new swap's partition UUID in `fstab`
- running `sudo touch /forcefsck`,

I rebooted the system.

---

After that, hibernation process fails on wake up. It says:

`cleaning journal.. clearing orphaned inode..`

I tried everything and somehow I discovered a workaround:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove plymouth
sudo apt-get install plymouth
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo reboot
```

Now everything seems to work fine, but I don't know what happened, how is plymouth connected with this swap partition problem?